# How to find out the scroll direction when you click on an anchor

Tags: javascript

I have a header that hides when scrolling down and shows when scrolling up. I also have a sticky banner that changes its top depending on the scroll so as not to interfere with the header. I have sticky anchors that, when clicked, need to be scrolled to sections. The problem is that if, when clicked, the page scrolls up, both the header and the banner are visible, but if it scrolls down, then only the banner because the header is hidden. Depending on the scroll direction, I need to add an offset so that the header or banner does not overlap the beginning of the section. How can I determine the scroll direction when clicked in order to add a different offset?

```js
  document.querySelectorAll('#page-list a[href^="#"]').forEach((anchor) => {
    anchor.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      const targetElement = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("href"));
      const headerHeight = document.querySelector("header").offsetHeight;
      const bannerHeight = document.querySelector(
        ".compare-form__sticky"
      ).offsetHeight;

      if (targetElement) {
        const elementPosition = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        const offset = -headerHeight - bannerHeight - 17;
        console.log(offset);
        const offsetPosition = elementPosition + window.scrollY + offset;

        window.scrollTo({
          top: offsetPosition,
          behavior: "smooth",
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Here you only shared your Javascript, so we would need to implement the structure ourselves just to reproduce your problem. People will likely not want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases you can simply create a proper event handler that does the checking properly. Here's an example, courtesy to https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/detect-the-scroll-direction-using-javascript which I used as my point of departure

```js
let lastScrollTop =
  window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  function handleScroll() {
    const scrollTopPosition =
      window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    if (scrollTopPosition > lastScrollTop) {
      console.log('scrolling down');
    } else if (scrollTopPosition < lastScrollTop) {
      console.log('scrolling up');
    }
    lastScrollTop =
      scrollTopPosition <= 0 ? 0 : scrollTopPosition;
  }

window.addEventListener(
  'scroll',
  handleScroll
  ,
  false,
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <style>
      body {
        margin: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>bobbyhadz.com</h2>

    <a href="#something">down</a>
    <h3>
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com
    </h3>
    <a href="#something">down</a>
    <h3>
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com
    </h3>
    <a href="#something">down</a>
    <h3>
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com
    </h3>
    <h3 id="something">
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com
    </h3>
    <a href="#something">up</a>
    <h3>
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com
    </h3>
    <a href="#something">up</a>
    <h3>
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com
    </h3>
    <a href="#something">up</a>
    <h3>
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com bobbyhadz.com
      bobbyhadz.com
    </h3>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But, another way is to simply be aware that if conditions are normal, then the buttons that are before the item they should lead to will scroll down whereas items that are below their target will scroll up. Example:

```js
for (let link of document.querySelectorAll(`a[href*="#"]`)) {
    let href = link.href.substring(link.href.indexOf("#"));
    let items = document.querySelectorAll(`a[href$="${href}"], ${href}`);
    link.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("scrolling " + ((items[0] === link) ? "down" : "up"));
    });
}
```

```css
.big-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<p id="top">we are at the top</p>
<a href="#bottom">scroll to bottom</a>
<div class="big-content"></div>
<a href="#top">scroll to top</a>
<p id="bottom">we are at the bottom</p>
```

You can also get the coordinates of the items you have and compare their position, courtesy to [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element) which was used as my starting point for this one:

```js
for (let link of document.querySelectorAll(`a[href*="#"]`)) {
    link.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let href = link.href.substring(link.href.indexOf("#"));
        let pair = document.querySelector(href);
        let linkRectangle = link.getBoundingClientRect();
        let pairRectangle = pair.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log((linkRectangle.y < pairRectangle.y) ? "down" : "up");
    });
}
```

```css
.big-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<p id="top">we are at the top</p>
<a href="#bottom">scroll to bottom</a>
<div class="big-content"></div>
<a href="#top">scroll to top</a>
<p id="bottom">we are at the bottom</p>
```